# Group rows based on +- threshold on high dimensional object

Tags: python

I have a large df with coordinates in multiple dimensions. I am trying to create classes (Objects) based on threshold difference between the coordinates. An example df is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'y': [10, 14, 5, 14, 3, 12],'z': [7, 6, 2, 43, 1, 40]})
```

So based on this df I want to group each row to a class based on -+ 2 across all coordinates.  So the df will have a unique group name added to each row. So the output for this threshold function is:

```
'x' 'y' 'z' 'group'
1   10  7   -
2   14  6   -
3   5   2   G1
4   14  43  -
5   3   1   G1
6   12  40  -
```

It is similar to clustering but I want to work on my own threshold functions. How can this done in python.

**EDIT**
To clarify the threshold is based on the similar coordinates. All rows with -+ threshold across all coordinates will be grouped as a single object. It can also be taken as grouping rows based on a threshold across all columns and assigning unique labels to each group.

Comment: I think this is going over my head, but I at least understood "the df will have a unique group name added to each row". However in the df below, some rows have a dash instead of a group name. What's up with that?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. If this question is specific to Pandas, please add the [tag:pandas] tag. You can [edit].

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. That is just for the example, it is undefined since it is not part of the threshold. In reality there will be multiple groups [G1, G2, ...........] based on the row values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, what you need is a function `apply`. It was not very clear from your statement, whether you need all the differences between the coordinates, or just the neighbouring differences (x-y and y-z). The row `5` has the difference between x and z coordinate 4, but is still assigned to the class G1.

That's why I wrote it for the two possibilities and you can just choose which one you need more:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def your_specific_function(row):
    '''
    For all differences use this:
        diffs = np.array([abs(row.x-row.y), abs(row.y-row.z), abs(row.x-row.z)])
    '''
    # for only x - y, y - z use this:
    diffs = np.diff(row)
    statement = all(diffs <= 2)
    if statement:
        return 'G1'
    else:
        return '-'
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'y': [10, 14, 5, 14, 3, 12],'z': [7, 6, 2, 43, 1, 40]})
df['group'] = df.apply(your_specific_function, axis = 1)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thank you very much :). It seems you have misunderstood. I have edited the original query so that it is more clear now. The difference is not between x and z but between row1 and row2 across all coordinates. Also what I provided is simple df in 3 dimensions but in reality it is in higher dimensions.